# R not displaying Arabic text correctly

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am running a simple unsupervised learning model on an Arabic text corpus, and the model is running well. However, I am having an issue with the plots that aren't working well as they are printing the Arabic characters from left to right, rather than the correct format of right to left.

Here are the packages I am using:

```
#Loading packages
library(tidyverse)
require(readxl)
require(writexl)
library(quanteda)
library(stm)
library(stmCorrViz)

theme_set(theme_bw())
```

The code for unsupervised topic models:

```
#Fitting a simple topic model (LDA)
#4 topics
lda_fit_c <- stm(dtm_c,
                 K = 4,
                 seed = 12345,
                 verbose = TRUE)
```

The issue occurs here with this code, where I am displaying the top 20 words in each topic:

```
plot.STM(lda_fit_c,
         type="labels",
         topics = 1:4)
```

Here is how the plot looks like, there are no errors with the code as I have tried it before with English text analyses, but with Arabic text it is not recognizing that it reads Right to left. Is there a way to adjust the default settings/format of the plot?

[image]

Comment: This is likely a problem that requires the maintainers of the stm package to handle: https://github.com/bstewart/stm/issues

Comment: Which R version your using ?

Comment: I am using R studio version 1.3.1093.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using old a version of R that is 3.2 or Less then those
versions does not handle Unicode in proper way. Try to install latest
version of R from https://cran.r-project.org/ and if required then
install all packages.

Comment: Please stop putting `>` before every line of text. This is for marking up quotes, not decorating your posts.